# How to implement Django Login using Facebook Registration

Tags: python, django, registration, authentication, facebook-login

I am new to Django and Facebook API and I would like to make my site only available to people who have a facebook account.

I have seen this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) for facebook registration and also have read some information about [django-socialregistartion](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-socialregistration/en/latest/contrib/facebook.html) .

I would like to know the difference between these two, or do they have to be done together? 
Also, which choice should work better if I still want @login_required to work in django and to get user_id and save it in a session?

Thanks

Comment: Try: https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth

Answer (score 3):

A popular option would be to use django-social-auth. It supports most authentication backends such as: Google, facebook, twitter, foursquare, etc.

Check out: http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#application-setup
for setting it up in your application.

For Facebook specifics see: https://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/facebook.html?highlight=facebook